# PassThrough Query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am new to using SQL server express for upsizing an Access (2007-2010) front end.

I wrote a class module that manages the SQL connection. for automating the call of functions, called procedures, and dynamic SQL strings, the last two return successfully a table using a SELECT statement that I attach to a DAO.recordset for further extracting results.

However when trying to do the same for an insert statement I encounter a problem
The SQL passthrough query is:

```
DECLARE @ret int;
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1;
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO dbo.[Munten](Munt, Decimalen, Volgorde) VALUES ('XYZ', 4, 99)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1;
END CATCH;
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
SET @ret = 0
ELSE
BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION T1;
    SET @ret = 1
END;
SELECT @ret as Retval;
```

that runs fine on SQL management studio returning a one column record but when executing the poassthrough query I get:

> "Passtrhough with returnrecords property set to true did not return any record"

Bellow the Access code:

```
Public Function AddRecord(TblName As String, Connectstring As String,      ParamArray Pars()) As Boolean
Dim s As String, I As Integer, str As String, sc As String, sv As String, rs As DAO.Recordset
ProcList.Start procmodule, "AddRecord", TblName, Connectstring, Pars()
On Local Error GoTo ErrHandler
With appdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    If Len(Connectstring) = 0 Then
       .Connect = StConnectstr
    Else
       .Connect = Connectstring
   End If
   For I = 0 To UBound(Pars)     ' ubound=-1 if no pars are passed
       If I Mod 2 = 0 Then     ' list of columns
          If I > 0 Then sc = sc & ", "
          sc = sc & Pars(I)
       Else                    '  list of values
          If I > 1 Then sv = sv & ", "
          If IsDate(Pars(I)) Then
              sv = sv & DateForSQL(Pars(I))
          ElseIf IsNumeric(Pars(I)) Then
              sv = sv & ConvDecimal(Pars(I), True)
          Else
              sv = sv & cSquote & Pars(I) & cSquote
         End If
       End If
   Next
   s = "INSERT INTO " & Me.WithSchema(TblName, IsTable) & "(" & sc & ") VALUES (" & sv & ")"
   str = EmbedTryCatch(s, .Connect)
   .ReturnsRecords = True
   .SQL = str
   AddRecord = (.OpenRecordset(, dbSQLPassThrough).Fields(0) <> 0)
   .Close
End With
Exit_Here:
     ProcList.Leave
     Exit Function
ErrHandler:
     If Error_message() Then Resume 0
     Resume Exit_Here
End Function

Private Function EmbedTryCatch(SQLstring As String, Connectstr As String) As String
EmbedTryCatch = "DECLARE @ret BIT;" & vbCrLf _
    & "BEGIN TRANSACTION T1;" & vbCrLf _
    & "BEGIN TRY" & vbCrLf _
        & SQLstring & vbCrLf _
    & "END TRY" & vbCrLf _
    & "BEGIN CATCH" & vbCrLf _
        & "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1;" & vbCrLf _
    & "END CATCH;" & vbCrLf _
    & "IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0" & vbCrLf _
        & "SET @ret = 0" & vbCrLf _
    & "ELSE" & vbCrLf _
        & "BEGIN" & vbCrLf _
            & "COMMIT TRANSACTION T1;" & vbCrLf _
            & "SET @ret = 1" & vbCrLf _
        & "END;" & vbCrLf _
    & "SELECT @ret as Retval;"
End Function
```

Where is the catch ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ReturnsRecords property of the query to False because an insert query does not return anything.

Also a good idea to include:

```
set nocount on
```

as the first line of your passthrough query - Access doesn't appear to understand the return messages that you would see in SSMS for example.

Comment: I know ... but how do you then detect a successful operation.

Comment: If there's no error returned from DAO then you can assume that the statement completed successfully. I suppose that you could always query the database again to check the insertion but I think that's probably unnecessary overhead.